# videojs stops playing HLS/M3U8 File

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, html5-video, video.js

I'm using videojs to play HLS/M3U8 on my server the video files load fine but after a few seconds of play it stops and I have to push pause/play to resume the stream I have a fast connection I don't know why this happens.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="" name="description">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <title>HLS Test</title>
    <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.7.1/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <video class="video-js" controls="" data-setup="{}" height="264" id=
    "my-video" poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg" preload="auto" width=
    "640"><source src=
    "http://184.72.239.149/vod/smil:BigBuckBunny.smil/playlist.m3u8" type=
    "application/x-mpegURL">
    <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and
    consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href=
    "http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5
    video</a></p></video> 

    <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.7.1/video.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/videojs-hls.min.js"></script> 
    <script>
            var player = videojs('my-video');
            player.play();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tested without `videojs`, using just a video tag?

Comment: no, I wish to use videojs for cross-platform

Comment: It seems to be a `videojs-hls` issue. Only the first 6 chunks are requested and then nothing. I tested with [Viblast Player](http://viblast.com/player/demo-user-stream/?stream=http://184.72.239.149/vod/smil:BigBuckBunny.smil/playlist.m3u8) and it was working just fine.
Offtopic: you code is affected by videojs [issue #2831](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/2831). I can barely get it working on my machine.

Comment: @SvetlinMladenov noted the videojs issue, I've found a solution where I just load [flashls](http://www.flashls.org/videojs/flash_demo.html) with videojs I don't know how this works but the demo works.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked it with Apple's [MediaStreamValidator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2235/_index.html) and it seems to be the case, that there are some discontinuities within the stream. There are players available which overcome such issues, like [Bitmovin's player](https://bitmovin.com/player/), but I would anyway recommend to check the stream settings.